# I am getting a NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner("Employees.txt");
        inputFile.useDelimiter(",");
        String[] strLastName = new String[10];
        String[] strFirstName = new String[10];
        double[] dHours = new double[10];
        double[] dPayRate = new double[10];
        int x = 0;

        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            strLastName[x] = inputFile.next();
            strFirstName[x] = inputFile.next();
            dHours[x] = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next());
            dPayRate[x] = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next());
            x++;
        }
        inputFile.close();
        String[] strFullName = FullName(strFirstName, strLastName);
        double[] dGrossPay = GrossPay(dHours, dPayRate);
        Output(strFullName, dHours, dPayRate, dGrossPay);
    }
```

This code is stopping at `strLastName[x] = inputFile.next();` and I am not sure why. It is coming up as a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` found.

Comment: You cannot invoke .next() multiple times within the while (hasNext()) loop...

Comment: Your loop checks if there is ONE next element. But then you call `next` FOUR times. This is obviously not safe, thus you run out of elements without any check.

Comment: You create your scanner on a `String`. But the string-constructor will read from the string as source. It will not interpret it as file. This is not doing what you thought it does. Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Why use `Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next())` and not `inputFile.nextDouble()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are calling `next()` four times for each one time you check `hasNext()`.  If your inputs are on the same line like this:

```
First Last hours rate
```

Then you should replace `inputFile.hasNext()` with `inputFile.hasNextLine()`.

If they are all on different lines like:

```
First
Last
hours
rate
```

Then you need to put an if statement before all the `inputFile.next()`'s (after the first one). Something like this:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        strLastName[x] = inputFile.next();
        if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
          strFirstName[x] = inputFile.next();
        }
        if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
          dHours[x] = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next());
        }
        if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
          dPayRate[x] = Double.parseDouble(inputFile.next());
        }
        x++;
    }
```

EDIT: Also the commenter below is correct, you are calling scanner on a string not a file.  You need to add the following at the beginning:

```
File myFile = new File("Employees.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
```

Comment: The actual issue of OP is that he is reading from a string, not a file. This answer does not solve OPs question.

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Edited my post to clear that up as well. He could still run into the problem I mentioned in my original answer so I left that too.

Comment: Without seeing your code or the specific error you're getting, I can't say exactly. But it is possible that you don't have File imported.  If thats the case you just need this line at the beginning where you import Scanner `import java.io.File;`

Answer (score 0):

You specified `useDelimiter(",")`, but is that really the delimiter of all values?

My guess is not, because `Employees.txt` is likely a CSV (Comma-Separated-Values) file, e.g. something like:

```
Doe,John,40,15.00
Smith,Jane,35,12.00
```

When you split that on comma, you get the following values:

```
Doe
John
40
15.00\nSmith
Jane
35
12.00
```

As you can see, the end-of-line did not cause a `15.00` and `Smith` to be two tokens.

Solutions:

1. **Use a CSV parser** *(highly recommended)*
2. Specify the correct delimiter *(not recommended, too error-prone)*

   ```
   inputFile.useDelimiter(",|\\R");
   ```
3. Use line-reading and split the lines:

   ```
   String[] strLastName = new String[10];
   String[] strFirstName = new String[10];
   double[] dHours = new double[10];
   double[] dPayRate = new double[10];
   try (BufferedReader inputFile = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("Employees.txt"))) {
       String line;
       for (int x = 0; (line = inputFile.readLine()) != null; x++) {
           String[] values = line.split(",");
           if (values.length != 4)
               throw new IOException("Bad data: " + line);
           strLastName[x] = values[0];
           strFirstName[x] = values[1];
           dHours[x] = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);
           dPayRate[x] = Double.parseDouble(values[3]);
       }
   }
   ```